# UIwebview not working properly

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiwebview

I have three UIwebView added from story board when i load them i add activity indicator to show loading progress and when loading is finish. Delegate of DidFinishLoading called. But i see the white color on uiwebview. When i again load the UIwebview when white screen is visible then it shows the error "Operation couldn't be completed" but when loading of UIwebview is properly done and again i reload with new url. then it does not show any error.
 Please somebody tell me.. Thanks in advance.

```
  NSString* urlgmap=@"www.google.com"

    NSURL *url_gmap = [NSURL URLWithString:urlgmap];
    NSURLRequest *request_gmap = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url_gmap  cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData  timeoutInterval:60];
    [self.wrae_one loadRequest:request_gmap];

    NSString* urlgrid=@"www.yahoo.com";

    NSURL *url_grid = [NSURL URLWithString:urlgrid];
    NSURLRequest *request_grid = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url_grid  cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData  timeoutInterval:60];
    [self.wrae_two loadRequest:request_grid];


        NSString* urlSmap=@"www.facebook.com";
        NSURL *url_smap = [NSURL URLWithString:urlSmap];
        NSURLRequest *request_smap = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url_smap  cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData  timeoutInterval:60];
```

Comment: let me know what is the reason to call 3 Url in same time in different time interval,

Comment: It is my requirement

Comment: then show ur screen shot of ur UI ,it is easy to optimize the answer

Comment: it just a white screen on the webvieew

Comment: r u tried  NSString* urlgmap=@"www.google.com" into  NSString* urlgmap=@"https://www.google.com"